# counting the number of key value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

I am working with dictionaries for the first time. I would like to know how I can count how many key value pairs there are in each dictionary where the value is 'available'. I know I probably use `len()`.

```
seats = {
  'A': {'A1':'available', 'A2':'unavailable', 'A3':'available'},
  'B': {'B1':'unavailable', 'B2':'available', 'B3':'available'}, 
  'C': {'C1':'available', 'C2':'available', 'C3':'unavailable'}, 
  'D': {'D1':'unavailable', 'D2':'available', 'D3':'available'} }

rowChoice = raw_input('What row? >> ')
numSeats = input('How many Seats? >> ')
```

I am very new to this, so I really need a very simple method and probably some annotation or explanation how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the following statement to count each nested dictionary's values:

```
{k: sum(1 for val in v.itervalues() if val == 'available') for k, v in seats.iteritems()}
```

This builds a new dictionary from the same keys as `seats` with each value being the number of seats available. The `sum(..)` with generator trick efficiently counts all values of the contained per-row dictionary where the value equals `'available'`.

Result:

```
{'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 2, 'D': 2}
```

To show available seats for a specific row you filter and just use `len()`:

```
row_available = [k for k, v in seats[rowChoice].iteritems() if v == 'available']
avail_count = len(row_available)
if avail_count:
    print 'there {is_are} {count} seat{plural} available in row {rowChoice}, seat{plural} {seats}'.format(
        is_are='are' if avail_count > 1 else 'is', count=avail_count, 
        plural='s' if avail_count > 1 else '', rowChoice=rowChoice, 
        seats=row_available[0] if avail_count == 1 else ' and '.join([', '.join(row_available[:-1]), row_available[-1]]))
```

For `rowChoice = 'A'` this prints:

```
there are 2 seats available in row A, seats A1 and A3
```

but it adjusts to form coherent sentences for more or fewer seats too.

Comment: `sum(val == 'available' for val in v.itervalues())` also works as booleans are summed as expected (True is 1, False is 0). An epic saving of 5 characters

Comment: @RobCowie: I avoid that syntax; the fact that `bool` are a subclass of `int` trips up even experienced Python programmers and makes the code less 'grokable' in my experience.

Comment: @RobCowie the `1 for ...` approach is certainly more explicit as to intent and if dealing with custom classes it's perfectly possible that `__eq__` could return objects apart from `True` and `False`... (try creating your own class with an `__eq__` that just returns 100....)

Comment: so how would i define one specific nested dictionary to seah from, say i wanted to search for available seats in row B, and simply print just what available seats are in this row like this:  **there are 2 seats available in row A, seats A1 and A3**.

Comment: Good point @JonClements, and Martijn you're most likely right about grokking the more explicit code. Just thought I'd mention it. Dunno why really...

Comment: could you simplify that please? i really am a complete novice. so could you show me an example without the elegant method of changing to plural. literally the most simple way.

Comment: @user2212774: The meat is in the lines before it; the `rows_available` list comprehension. The `.format()` is just a way to print the info. Play with the `str.join()` method I used, etc. You'll figure it out. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `collections.Counter` and `itertools.chain`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

print Counter(chain.from_iterable(i.itervalues() for i in seats.itervalues()))
# Counter({'available': 8, 'unavailable': 4})
```

Comment: Cant get it to work for me. I get `ERROR:root:'int' object has no attribute 'itervalues'`. Also I'd like to count the 3 object in the dictionary's (sub) values. any ideas?